# I have 2 models need to references, but first model is a self-referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, self-reference

### My lab

```
rails new test1 -d mysql
rails g scaffold User name
rails g migration AddTeacherToUsers #add_reference :users, :teacher, index: true 
rails g scaffold Lab name user:references
rails db:create db:migrate
```

### System message

> Created database 'test1_development'
> Created database 'test1_test'
> 20230416164900 CreateUsers: migrating ==
> create_table(:users)
> 0.1837s
> 20230416164900 CreateUsers: migrated (0.1839s) ==
>
> 20230416164941 AddTeacherToUsers: migrating ==
> add_reference(:users, :teacher, {:index=>true})
> 0.4567s
> 20230416164941 AddTeacherToUsers: migrated (0.4568s) ==
>
> 20230416165121 CreateLabs: migrating ==
> create_table(:labs)
> 0.4219s
> 20230416165121 CreateLabs: migrated (0.4221s) ==

```
rails g migration AddTeacherToLabs teacher:references
vi apps/models/lab.rb # belongs_to :teacher, class_name: "User"
rails db:migrate
```

### This is error message:

> 20230416165540 AddTeacherToLabs: migrating ==
> add_reference(:labs, :teacher, {:foreign_key=>true})
> rails aborted!
> StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
>
> Mysql2::Error: Table 'test1_development.teachers' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `teachers`
> /home/patrick/test1/db/migrate/20230416165540_add_teacher_to_labs.rb:3:in `change'  /home/patrick/test1/bin/rails:9:in` <top (required)>'
> /home/patrick/test1/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'  bin/rails:3:in` load'
> bin/rails:3:in `'
>
> Caused by:
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'test1_development.teachers' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `teachers`
> /home/patrick/test1/db/migrate/20230416165540_add_teacher_to_labs.rb:3:in `change'  /home/patrick/test1/bin/rails:9:in` <top (required)>'
> /home/patrick/test1/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'  bin/rails:3:in` load'
> bin/rails:3:in `'
>
> Caused by:
> Mysql2::Error: Table 'test1_development.teachers' doesn't exist
> /home/patrick/test1/db/migrate/20230416165540_add_teacher_to_labs.rb:3:in `change'  /home/patrick/test1/bin/rails:9:in` <top (required)>'
> /home/patrick/test1/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'  bin/rails:3:in` load'
> bin/rails:3:in `'
>
> Caused by:
> Mysql2::Error: Can't create table `test1_development`.`labs` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
> /home/patrick/test1/db/migrate/20230416165540_add_teacher_to_labs.rb:3:in `change'  /home/patrick/test1/bin/rails:9:in` <top (required)>'
> /home/patrick/test1/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'  bin/rails:3:in` load'
> bin/rails:3:in `'
> Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)

#### How can i do? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `teacher_id` column to point to the users table you need to configure the foreign key explicitly in the migration:

```
class AddTeacherToLabs < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_reference :labs, :teacher, 
       null: false, 
       foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
  end
end
```

I don't think you can add this option from the generator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this problem has been bugging me for a week now!

Comment: I found a new problem! The Lab.first.teacher is not a full model, so I can't access Professor.count, Professor.name or anything else, I just can use professor_id :(

Comment: Thats a separate question.